# Haskell: Hiding failures in lazy IO

Tags: haskell, lazy-io

This is a noob question.

I'd like to write a function which provides a lazy stream of images, presumably something like:

```
imageStream :: [IO Image]
```

Unfortunately, the function which reads images can fail, so it looks like:

```
readImage :: IO (Maybe Image)
```

So, the function I *can* write looks like:

```
maybeImageStream :: [IO (Maybe Image)]
```

How do I implement a function such as the following, while still keeping lazy IO?

```
flattenImageStream :: [IO (Maybe Image)] -> [IO Image]
```

Semantically, when you ask `flattenImageStream` for the next image, it should iterate through the list and attempt to read each image. It does this until it finds an image that loads, and returns it.

EDIT: There seems to be some disagreement in the answers.
Some have suggested solutions that use `sequence`, but I'm pretty sure I tested that and found it destroys laziness.
(I'll test it again to be sure when I get back to my computer.)
Someone also suggested using `unsafeInterleaveIO`.
From the documentation for that function, it seems it would work, but obviously I want to respect the type system as much as possible.

Comment: Are you sure you want an `[IO Image]`?  Wouldn't `IO [Image]` be easier to work with?

Comment: @jwodder, I may be mistaken, but I think `IO [Image]` implies the images will be loaded strictly, while I want to load them lazily due to memory and other things.

Comment: Nah they'll still be lazy.  if you return [IO Image] you haven't loaded anything.  You just have a list of io functions to run to load images.

Comment: You'll need `unsafeInterleaveIO`.

Comment: I was wrong @luqui is right.  They won't be lazy. I tested. http://lpaste.net/95074

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `ListT` from `pipes`, which provides a safer alternative to lazy `IO` that does the right thing in this case.

The way you model your lazy stream of potentially failing images is:

```
imageStream :: ListT IO (Maybe Image)
```

Assuming that you had some image loading function of type:

```
loadImage :: FileName -> IO (Maybe Image)
```

.. then the way you build such a stream would be something like:

```
imageStream = do
    fileName <- Select $ each ["file1.jpg", "file2.jpg", "file3.jpg"]
    lift $ loadImage fileName
```

If you use the [`dirstream` library](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-DirStream-Library), then you can even lazily stream over the directory contents, too.

The function that filters out only the successful results would have this type:

```
flattenImageStream :: (Monad m) => ListT m (Maybe a) -> ListT m a
flattenImageStream stream = do
    ma <- stream
    case ma of
        Just a  -> return a
        Nothing -> mzero
```

Notice that this function works for any base monad, `m`.  There is nothing `IO`-specific about it.  It also preserves laziness!

Applying `flattenImage` to `imageStream`, gives us something of type:

```
finalStream :: List IO Image
finalStream = flattenImage imageStream
```

Now let's say that you have some function that consumes these images, of type:

```
useImage :: Image -> IO ()
```

If you want to process the final `ListT` using the `useImage` function, you just write:

```
main = runEffect $
    for (every finalStream) $ \image -> do
        lift $ useImage image
```

That will then lazily consume the image stream.

Of course, you could also play code golf and combine all of that into the following much shorter version:

```
main = runEffect $ for (every image) (lift . useImage)
  where
    image = do
        fileName   <- Select $ each ["file1.jpg", "file2.jpg", "file3.jpg"]
        maybeImage <- lift $ loadImage fileName           
        case maybeImage of
            Just img -> return img
            Nothing  -> mzero
```

I'm also thinking of adding a `fail` definition for `ListT` so that you could just write:

```
main = runEffect $ for (every image) (lift . useImage)
  where
    image = do
        fileName <- Select $ each ["file1.jpg", "file2.jpg", "file3.jpg"]
        Just img <- lift $ loadImage fileName           
        return img
```

Comment: This works great, but after reading more about `pipes` I decided to go with `Producer` / `Consumer` / `spawn` for my full solution, which needs `pipes-concurrency`. It's an impressive library; thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

as suggested u can turn [m a] into m [a] using sequence

so you get:

```
imageStream :: IO [Image]
```

then you can use cayMaybes from Data.Maybe to keep just the Just values:

```
catMaybes `liftM` imageStream
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this as requested seems like it would require knowing outside of the IO monad whether a value inside IO was `Nothing`, and as IO is designed to prevent its values from "leaking out" into the outside purely functional world (`unsafePerformIO` notwithstanding), this would be impossible.  Instead, I recommend producing an `IO [Image]`: use `sequence` to convert the `[IO (Maybe Image)]` to `IO [Maybe Image]`, and then use `Data.Maybe.catMaybes` within the IO monad (e.g., with `fmap` or `liftM`) to convert to `IO [Image]`, e.g.:

```
flattenImageStream = fmap catMaybes $ sequence maybeImageStream
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried this, and I got a non-lazy list of `Image`. I could tell it's non-lazy because I log whenever an image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of these other answers are doing exactly what you want.  Because i'm pretty sure `catMaybes` will just skip over the image and not try to reload it.  If you want to just keep trying to reload an image try this.

```
flattenImageStream :: [IO (Maybe Image)] -> IO [Image]
flattenImageStream xs = mapM untilSuc xs

untilSuc :: IO (Maybe a) -> IO a
untilSuc f = do
   res <- f
   case res of
      Nothing -> untilSuc f
      Just i  -> return i
```

But what you are doing is kind of strange.  What if you have the wrong file path?  What if the image simply can't be loaded?  You'll just try to load an image forever.  You should probably have a number of times to try and load the image before it gives up.

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to do. I want to transparently skip images that don't load, not keep trying forever to load them.

Comment: "it should keep attempting to read images until it succeeds, and return that image."  Okay, but it wasn't very explicit in your question.  Use their answers then.

Comment: My bad; I'll edit the question. Thanks for pointing this out.